# Correct way to get Region Name by using hbase API

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to fetch "Region Name" for a "table" using HBase API.

The setup is mentioned below:

1. Hbase pseudo-distributed installation (version 0.98.7).
2. Hadoop 2.5.1 installation.

The Hbase contains very few tables for testing purpose. And information about available regions are shown below from the web UI.

[image]

"region name" corresponding to the table "test_table" has been highlighted purposefully.

Now, I have been trying to get these region information from the java based API of hbase using below codes.

```
void scanTable(String tabName){

        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        try{
            HTable table = new HTable(config, tabName);
            org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName tn = table.getName();

            HRegionInfo hr =  new HRegionInfo(tn);
            System.out.println(hr.getRegionNameAsString());

            table.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever, I pass a table name, say "test_table", the regionName is returned differently on every run.

RUN 1:

```
test_table,,1419247657866.77b98d085239ed8668596ea659a7ad7d.
```

RUN 2:

```
test_table,,1419247839479.d3097b0f4b407ca827e9fa3773b4d7c7.
```

RUN 3:

```
test_table,,1419247859921.e1e39678fa724d7168cd4100289c4234.
```

I assume that I am using wrong method to generate "region_name" or my approach is wrong.
Please help me to get the region information for given table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a getTableRegions() in HBaseAdmin which returns all the region info for the table name you want.

List getTableRegions(final TableName tableName)

Below is the method that outputs region name for a given table name.

```
void getRegionOfTable(String tabName){
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName tn = org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.valueOf(tabName);
    org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    HRegionInfo ob;
    try{
        HBaseAdmin hba = new HBaseAdmin(config);
        List<HRegionInfo> lr = hba.getTableRegions(tn);
        Iterator<HRegionInfo> ir = lr.iterator();
        while(ir.hasNext()){
            ob = ir.next();
            System.out.println(ob.getRegionNameAsString());
        }
        hba.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Your code produce a different result every time, because you are building a new "region" with a different timestamp every time. Also that code assumes that your table has a single region.

Comment: Thanks @th30z. It works although I have identified an another way to get correct Region name. I'll update your answer with the complete java method that outputs region name. :)

Comment: Also this wouldn't work for versions below 0.96. As org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName was introduced only after 0.96/