# How to scan hbase in a map reduce job

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

I need to run hourly analysis of elements that are stored in hbase, which means for each element, I need to get the previous hour's data to analyze.  The only problem is it's taking me more than 1 hour to scan everything when using a for loop without mapreduce.  There are over 100,000 elements we are storing data on.

The data isn't contiguous and it is in time series, coming in every 2 minutes.  There is a hash to prevent scanning/writing hotspots so the key looks like this:

hash_elementName_epochTimestamp,  e.g. 100_element_1234567890.

I tried to write a mapreduce program using the TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob method to run my scan.  However, the TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob method takes one scan object and I can't figure out how to scan all the elements that I need without making 100,000 separate scan objects and without scanning the whole table.

Someone else said there was a [spark-hbase connector library](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector) I could use to leverage Spark and store everything in memory to query quickly.  The problem is this code is written in Scala, which I don't know and can't spend time to learn right now.

Is there a spark-hbase connector that's in Java?  Is there a way to utilize the TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob method scan Hbase quickly, even with 100,000 non-contiguous scan ranges?

EDIT: Someone suggested that I should use a start and end time filter.  The problem is I'm not interested in every single element.  There are only certain elements I'm interested in.  When I made my query via the for loop, I passed in the elements I was interested in.  Now with the TableMapReduceUtil, I can only make one scan object.

Comment: What version of map-reduce and what version of HBase are you using? I haven't used MR in a while, but when I did (MR v1), you define how your dataset is split. It is most optimal with HBase to have one split per region. You can determine the region splits by using the HBase API. [See this answer for how to do it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602013/correct-way-to-get-region-name-by-using-hbase-api i don't think your schema will really benefit you because you have a hash at the beginning of the key, you can't quickly determine what kind of element you're looking at by the prefix

Comment: @Samuel, Thx for your help.  I'm using hbase-client and hbase-server v1.2.    I'm looking at your answer to see if I can get it working with my setup.  If there's anything else you can think of, please let me know.